# How is user search made relevant with first degree connections?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, search, graph, social-networking

On any social media platform when I search for users, I get results sorted by count of mutual connections (first degree connections)

Lets say I search for a user named "Rishi"
As shown in attached image below
Rishi Xyz was top suggestion as we had 10 mutual connections
Followed by others descending

[image: help]

For full text searches we could always use elastic search, but how do we sort them on mutual connections

How would this scale for millions of users

Any relevant articles where I can study more about its implementation could help